# Bound Item To DependencyProperty Not Propagating Value

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-8.1

This is the property that I defined inside a CustomButton:

```
 public bool IsOn
    {
        get  { return (bool)GetValue(IsOnProperty); }
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(IsOnProperty, value);
            if (IsOn) 
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "On", true);
            else 
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Off", true);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOnProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsOn", 
                                    typeof(bool), 
                                    typeof(ImageButton), 
                                    new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

In my Xaml it is bound to another Boolean list below:

```
IsOn="{Binding Sender.IsPinned, Mode=OneWay}"
```

and Sender.IsPinned raises the PropertyChange

```
public bool IsPinned 
        {
            get { return _model.IsPinned; }
            set 
            { 
                _model.IsPinned = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsPinned");
            }
        }


protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

When  IsPinned is changed, IsOn doesn't see the change at all. But when I save the data and refresh the UI, the change is reflected on IsOn.

It seems like the PropertyChangedEventHandler is not implemented but when debugged, it calls the event.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code (not shown) is changing the `_model.IsPinned` directly and not changing the `IsPinned` property which has the binding notification. That would lead to an update failure to `IsOn`.

The backing variable `_model.IsPinned` which is used by `IsPinned` cannot be changed by anything other than the `IsPinned` setter; such that its change can be noticed by `IsOn`.

One has to change `IsPinned` property directly (*which subsequently changes `_model.IsPinned`*) otherwise the binding cannot pick up on any changes to the backing store `_model.IsPinned`.

-- **Or** ---

When the variable `_model.IsPinned` is changed outside of the setter, simply call `RaisePropertyChanged("IsPinned");` to signify the change to `IsOn`.

Comment: I set it to false before null, and it didn't work. I set to null/true and it didn't fixed anything.

Comment: @aaram When you say "IsPinned is changed", do you mean the value on the model's `_model.IsPinned` changes or the property `IsPinned` changes and **IT** then changes `_model_IsPinned`?

Comment: @aaram see changed answer.

Comment: @aaram  Code (either the `IsPinned` setter or something else) has to call `RaisePropertyChanged("IsPinned")`, otherwise the the binding tied to `IsOn` will never notice the change to `_model.IsPinned`.

Comment: _model is a private class and no other part of the code has access to change _model.IsPinned, I set IsPinned property.

Comment: Just to add a little bit of more information, this DependencyProperty belongs to a cusomControl and I used this control inside a UserControl.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @OmegaMan

Comment: @aaram, Ok I understand. My thought is the *refresh* of the screen works...if that works, then why isn't the Property Change propagating to the `IsOn`. (?)

Comment: Refreshing the screen does work, when it is being loaded or refreshed, the IsOn property will be set to IsPinned property.

Comment: By the way, two way binding works from IsOn to IsPinned, not the other way around tho.

Answer (score 0):

That is how I solved it

```
public bool IsOn
        {
            get 
            { 
                return (bool)GetValue(IsOnProperty); 
            }
            set 
            { 
                SetValue(IsOnProperty, value);               
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOnProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsOn", typeof(bool), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(false, Changed));

        private static void Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            ImageButton img = (ImageButton)d;
            if (img.IsOn)
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(img, "On", true);
            else
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(img, "Off", true);
        }
```